# Jquery div move with mouse

Tags: jquery, css

I have a small piece of Jquery im trying to get to work.

```
$(document).on('bind', 'mousemove', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.circle2').css({
       left:  e.pageX + 20,
       top:   e.pageY
    });
});
```

Basically the circle is supposed to follow your mouses position. However there seems to be something that im missing.

Here is the CSS for the circle:

```
.circle2{
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 90px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w4b8ykqu/

Comment: Please add jquery to fiddle.

Comment: It is? :) bottom left? ^^

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w4b8ykqu/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have binded [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) `mousemove` wrongly

```
//remove "bind"
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.circle2').css({
        left: e.pageX + 20,
        top: e.pageY
    });
});
```

**Run Snippet**

```js
//remove "bind"
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.circle2').css({
        left: e.pageX + 20,
        top: e.pageY
    });
});
```

```css
.circle2 {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 spacc">
        <div class="circle2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this approach:

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(e){ //Remove "bind"
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.circle2').css({
           left:  e.pageX + 20,
           top:   e.pageY
        });
    });
```

and add jQuery library

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/w4b8ykqu/5/

The format for binding an event:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

and `bind` is not an event or selector.

**Reference:** http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.circle2').css({
        left: e.pageX + 20,
        top: e.pageY
    });
});
```

remove bind

[mousemove documentation](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/)

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/u7579rq3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo for the same:

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 spacc">
        <div class="circle2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle2{
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 90px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('.circle2').offset({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY + 20
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/SYwba/736/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) { 
         e.preventDefault();
         $('.circle2').css({
             left: e.pageX + 20,
             top: e.pageY
         });
     });

});
```

Comment: While this can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.